# Are bryophyte sporangia multicellular?

Tags: plant-anatomy

My research on the matter can be summarized in a sentence: "It [sporangium] can be composed of a single cell or can be multicellular" (Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sporangium). Yet there shouldn't be a reply placed between "They are" and "They aren't" test options, speaking of "Are bryophyte sporangia multicellular?". A link to the source where I could ascertain whether the bryophyte sporangia is multicellular (if I could ascertain) is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Embryophyta (land plants), including bryophytes, the sporangium is usually a multicellular structure.

[image: Life cycle of a hornwort. The dehisced sporangium is shown releasing spores and elaters.]

Perhaps you meant to ask about the number of *spore mother cells* (SMCs) in each sporangium? That varies across groups. In bryophytes, each sporangium has many SMCs, and accordingly produces a large number of spores. (Contrast this with angiosperms, where a megasporangium [called an ovule] has only one megaspore mother cell.)

---

**References and further reading:**

1. https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-biology/chapter/bryophytes/
2. https://www.britannica.com/science/plant-development

**Image attribution:**

By LadyofHats. (Public domain;
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hornwort_structures.jpg)

Comment: Thanks! Referring also to the "Great Soviet Encyclopedia" 3rd edition (1970-1979), in particular, a sporangium is multicellular in higher plants. Now, scarcely do I understand why a sporangium of angiosperms is multicellular if it has a single megaspore mother cell. Is this because of four megaspores - the daughter cells in the process of meiosis in a megaspore mother cell?

Comment: @Lesya It is multicellular because it has cells OTHER THAN the megaspore mother cell (and its derivatives): namely the nucellus. See https://botit.botany.wisc.edu/botany_130/diversity/plants/Vascular_Plants/Magnoliophyta/Angiosperms/ovule-labelled.html.